# How to create a directory in Scripter Automation

Tags: vbscript, directory, basic

Is it possible to create a directory in Scripter Automation?
If so, how?

I need to call ActiveX plugin.
In VB you can call it with

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\Documents and Settings\AllUsers
\Documents\NewDirectory")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a FSO and use its .CreateFolder method:

```
>> Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>> s = "NewDirectory"
>> WScript.Echo CStr(oFS.FolderExists(s))
>> oFS.CreateFolder s
>> WScript.Echo CStr(oFS.FolderExists(s))
>>
Falsch
Wahr
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ekkehard.Horner**

Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for!

WScript.Echo wasn't needed!

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
directory = path
If(FSO.FolderExists(directory) Then
Else FSO.CreateFolder directory
```